# How to change grid color with a button click?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've trying to create an app in Windows Phone 8 that changes the color of a Grid when a button is clicked, and I could use some help.

I've searched around the web, but can't seem to find any answer that satisfies my need.

All I have currently is this:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.Next(0, 1);

    if (number == 1)
    {
        yesornogrid.Background = SolidColorBrush 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

use the following name space:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

And then try:

```
yesornogrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush([Some Color]);
```

For Example:

```
yesornogrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
```